# Automating a Machine Learning workflow with AWS SageMaker, AWS StepFunctions, AWS Eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I am creating a simple ML workflow within AWS SageMaker and trying to orchestrate it using AWS StepFunctions. Currently, I was able to create a steps with Python SDK and execute from within the SageMaker Notebook.

Ultimately, I would like to invoke this once a week automatically using AWS eventbridge.
When I tested a simple Rules in eventbridge using the same state machine created after successfully running from sagemaker, the stepfunctions fails.
The current Python SDK doesn't tell us how to automate.

Can anyone suggest/show me how I can make this automation work.
For simplicity, I have included a single step workflow below:
Thanks everyone!

```
# Install necessary upgrades
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade pip
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade stepfunctions

# import necessary libraries .. 
# e.g ...
import boto3
import sagemaker
import stepfunctions

# There are many more libraries not shown here...
```

Next I defined a simple processing steps as follows:

```
execution_input = ExecutionInput(
    schema={
        "PreprocessingJobName": str,
    }
)
```

```
# Using Script processing

inputs=[
    ProcessingInput(
        source=input_data_path, 
        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input",
        input_name="input_data"
    ),
    ProcessingInput(
        source='s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, 'script_processing/code/preprocessing.py'), 
        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/code",
        input_name="code",
    ),
]

outputs=[
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data",
                     source="/opt/ml/processing/output/train",
                     destination="{}/{}".format(output_data_path, "train_data")),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_data",
                     source="/opt/ml/processing/output/test",
                     destination="{}/{}".format(output_data_path, "test_data")),
]

# Create a SageMaker ScriptProcessor instance
script_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    command=['python3'],
    image_uri=preprocessing_image,
    role=sagemaker_execution_role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
)

# Create Processing Step
processing_step = ProcessingStep(
    "my-processing-step",
    processor=script_processor,
    job_name=execution_input["PreprocessingJobName"],    
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    container_arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"],
    container_entrypoint=["python3", "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/preprocessing.py"],
)
```

Finally putting together the steps:

```
workflow_graph = Chain(
    [processing_step]
    )

# Next, we define the workflow
branching_workflow = Workflow(
    name = "MyWorkflow-processing", 
    definition = workflow_graph,
    role = workflow_execution_role
)

branching_workflow.create()


# Execute the workflow
workflow_execution = branching_workflow.execute(
    inputs = { 
        "PreprocessingJobName": "preprocess-{}-{}".format(uuid.uuid1().hex),        
    }
)
execution_output = workflow_execution.get_output(wait=True)
```

Upon execution from Jupyter Notebook, it runs successfully.

[image]

Comment: You would like to schedule aws step function Once a week ?

Comment: What error do you see when the step function fails?

Comment: @SUDARSHAN, yes I would like to schedule this workflow to get triggered once a week.

Comment: @KiritThadaka, I get error like:
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'my-processing-step' (entered at the event id #2). The JSONPath '$$.Execution.Input['PreprocessingJobName']' specified for the field 'ProcessingJobName.$' could not be found in the input '{\"Execution\":{\"Id\":\"arn:aws:states:us-west-###########\:execution:MyWorkflow-processing.......

Comment: If you look at the Jupyter snippet above in my post, there is a line of code that says: 
```
execution_input = ExecutionInput(
    schema={
        "PreprocessingJobName": str,
    }
)
```
My guess is when State machine is triggered outside of Jupyter, this parameter is not getting passed into the processing step. 
How can make sure, this is parameters gets passed into the flow?

Answer (score 0):

If scheduling is the issue that you are facing then you can use this cron

1. Create an EventBridge Rule

   Cron expression

   0 1 ? * SAT *

[image]

2. sample code to start step function from aws lambda function

   ```
   client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
    workflowInput={
    'ID' : ID
    }

    step_function='Give unique name to setp function exceution'
    response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:***************',
    name=step_function,
    input= json.dumps(workflowInput)
    )
   ```

workflowInput input will be the input for your step function .
The error that your are facing can also be resolved if you pass input carefully .
It takes input in JSON format .
You can keep adding more element to the json .

**Managing Long running task in step function .**

Lambda will invoke the step function and will not wait for its completion any way .
what you can do in your use case is ,You can have another another event bridge for step function status change on  (SUCCEEDED, FAILED, TIMED_OUT, or ABORTED).
Once your step function is SUCCEEDED lambda will invoke and notify with all details or event you can have execution history of step function also .

I hope that works for your .

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tips. But I am afraid, this may not work in my case because of lambda limit of < 15 minutes. My entire workflow can go beyond hour.
May I ask you, if you know how we can run a notebook within a sagemaker instance using a Lambda function? 

Scenario:
I have a Sagemaker Instance that has multiplenobooks. 
But is it possible to spin that instance and then run a 'specific' notebook from lambda?
Many thanks!

Comment: I think you can do that .Can you have a look my updated answer .There are other ways also that can be used

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use Lambda to invoke the Step Function for which I used event bridge to trigger the lambda. I will try the second event bridge for step function status change.